# Zipping downsampled data (with anti-aliasing) comes out bigger than zipping the original

Tags: zip, compression, signals, archive

So I have 10 files, each holds about 150 signals of floating point numbers of size 10000. (They are SEGY files, which hold siesmic data)

Each one of those files weighs about 95MB.
When I compress them all together using Zip I get an approximately 440MB archive.

I downsampled those signals by a factor of 2, so each file is now about 47MB. I zipped them all together and got an archive of size 660MB.

How is that possible?

EDIT:
Apparently, I downsampled with an anti-aliasing filter. When removing that filter, the compression behaved as expected.

Still wondering, why would an anti-aliasing filter cause this kind of behavior?

Comment: No, it's not possible, at least the way you describe it. zip will never expand by more than a fraction of a percent on large inputs, as you have. You'd need to provide much more detail on _exactly_ what you're doing to get this result.

Comment: @MarkAdler Apparently, I used an anti-aliasing filter when downsampling, which caused this behavior. I'm still wondering how the filter causes this much of a difference in compression rates. I edited the post to reflect this

Comment: Which zip utility? Which platform? What compression algorithm? If you're using a command line exactly what command? These types of details would be helpful.

Comment: @Jeff multiple standard compression algorithms, including gzip, bzip, 7z, winrar

Answer (score 1):

[Seismic data isn't compressible](https://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/S1319157818301101) with general compression tools like zip. You need [special compress like BWT](https://www.researchgate.net/publication/2558633_Improvements_to_the_Burrows-Wheeler_Compression_Algorithm_After_BWT_Stages).

> why would an anti-aliasing filter cause this kind of behavior?

Compression works on eliminating similarities in the data with shorthands. Any time you see increases in size, you are experiencing data that looks like random data to the compressor. It attempts to compress, but ultimately makes the file larger.

**Aliasing** in seismic data presents as distortions of frequency introduced by inadequately sampling a signal. This also can lead to signal to noise issues. Anti-aliasing attempts to smith this out. The net effect is prior to anti-aliasing you have less datapoints than after anti-aliasing. The additional data points reduces the chance the compression algorithm will be able to eliminate similar chunks of data.

Comment: Still doesn't explain what exactly causes anti aliases signals to be harder to compress

Comment: I added a note on what anti-aliasing may make the compression worse.